# Using SO on a mobile device

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, mobile-web

Yesterday, I was browsing the mobile Stack Overflow site. I noticed one thing: the textareas where you write your comments/answers are very buggy. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2, with the standard Android browser (Android version 4.1.2). There are a number of things that aren't working when typing your comment/answer.

- Automatic spacing with Swype is disabled (however this might be because of Swype, not the site).
- Text navigation buttons (step left, step right, select text, copy text etc.) doesn't work with the on-screen keyboard, and selecting text by holding your finger over text is extremely difficult.
- When you paste something it always seems to be pasted at the top of your text, no matter where you try to paste it.
- Replying to another comment ("@Example User") does not show suggested people to reply to, like the full site does.

Is there anything I can do to solve these issues/bugs, or is it in the hands of Stack Overflow itself, and if so, should it be looked into?

**Edit:** I was using the mobile version of the site when noticing these bugs.

Comment: where you using the normal version or mobile version of site ?

Comment: I was using the mobile version of the site. Will put that into my question.

Comment: **Posted from my pain-free iOS device.**

Comment: Sorry, it's just that none of the bugs mentioned show up in iOS on the mobile version.

Comment: I understand that, most likely because Android and iOS devices use different browsers. However I'm not the only one with an Android :) There's gotta be a solution to these bugs to make browsing smoother, for everyone!

Comment: Android w/mobile Chrome, here. Only thing I repro us the last item; not sure it is meant to be a feature. (Autosuggest on tags works for me)

Comment: What Android version are you running? And yes, autosuggest on tags works for me as well.

Comment: Do I have to admit? (2.3.6)

Comment: Anything you say can and will be used against you. Try going on the mobile SO site with the default browser instead of Chrome and check for bugs?

Comment: Of those issues only the last one seems related to SO, rather than your keyboard/input app.

Comment: I realize that, however SO is the only site where I have run in to these problems, or anything close to them, hence my question.

Comment: I'm on Android Chrome, and paste doesn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your first three points seem to be related to swype and not our site directly. The fourth point is by design -- the mobile site has limited functionality and name autocomplete is not supported on it.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197719/add-the-comments-auto-complete-to-mobile-theme

Comment: Second one is **not** Swype's fault. Navigation functionality on every single IME doesn't work.

Comment: Is this answer, concerning the "wontfix" state of the autocompletion for mobile phoes, still valid? Since 2014 mobile phones have grown in their spread and computational power. Maybe you want now reduce the gap between desktop and mobile websites.

Comment: They have, @Cubo78, to the extent that they've essentially retired the mobile-only view. As a replacement, they have made the normal view responsive, which allows you to use it on mobile or any other device. Because it is the same site, it supports all the normal features. Note also that Sklivvz posted this answer back in 2014 when he was an employee of Stack Exchange. That is no longer the case, so you aren't going to be able to convince him to actually change anything. Or me, for that matter.