# Add the comments @ auto-complete to mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile-web, comment-replies

When browsing the mobile theme of Stack Exchange sites, when I type a @ sign followed by a letter, it never auto completes the username for the comment like it does on the full site theme.

I think this feature is needed as it prevents me from responding to specific comments.

Can this please be added to the mobile theme as well?

Comment: The mobile theme simply does not include the required JS for this, it does work if you browse the full site version on mobile device. I'll change this into proper feature request.

Comment: Note that users will still get pings (replies) on comments if you at least have the first three characters of their username. The super-helpful-popup-thingy isn't needed for this to happen.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess I found the answer here: [Add "Reply" link to comment that pre-populates comment box with @username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/add-reply-link-to-comment-that-pre-populates-comment-box-with-username?rq=1)

I re-posted it below:

---

We're actually moving away from indoctrinating users into the @username cult for comment replies, for these reasons:

1. AXIOM: A bunch of comments filled with `@username` are harder to read and noisier than those which are not. The goal of our sites is to *increase* signal-to-noise, not reduce it.
2. The average number of comments on a SO question is 2.5.
3. The median number of comments on a SO question is ZERO.
4. Post owners are *always* notified of comments on their posts.
5. If there are only two people talking in comments, the post owner and one other person, we auto-infer replies in that situation as well; that is:

   > Question? -- User A
   >   Clarifying comment. -- User B
   >   Response to clarifying comment. -- User A

   In the above case, A would be notified of B's comment. And B would be notified of A's response to his comment as well. Notice the conspicuous lack of `@username` anywhere!
6. If the average number of comments is 2.5 -- let's go nucking futs here and assume one of those is a reply from the post owner back to the person who left the comment -- then *statistically speaking, @username is not required at all*.

For these reasons, I am loathe to perpetuate the idea that people have to use @username at all, **except when they need to talk to another commenter.**

(Note that I am *in no way* objecting to an organic mention of someone's name in a comment, in the form of "If you consider blaz, Greg, I think you'll see that fromenting the hogribicator when the z-axis is above 96 degrees is your best option.")

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly does this answer the feature request? Do you mean you no longer want that request to be done?

Answer (score 0):

The officials doesn't seem to want to implement this on mobile site. See [this response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231607/350567). As well, that question was tagged [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), meaning not implementing that is intentional.